# respond_to works only for the first MIME type in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Straight-forward enough problem: everything renders just fine if I remove either geojson or csv, but when both are in the block, the first one is rendered no matter what Content-Type header I send along (`text/csv` or `vnd.geo+json`). I do have custom MIME types and renderers, but these don't seem to be the problem since when I use one or the other, everything works as expected, but it is only when I try to reference multiple formats does only the first format end up being used, regardless of header.

```rb
      def all
        resource = Thing.where.not(thing_type: BaseThing::ONE_OF_THE_THINGS).order(:unique_id)
        respond_to do |format|
          format.geojson do
            render geojson: Things::GeoSerializer.to_geojson(resource)
          end
          format.csv do
            render csv: Things::CsvSerializer.to_csv(resource), filename: 'things'
          end
        end
      end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ah; Rails expects the header to be `Accept`, not `Content-Type`.